# Google Calendar error 400

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to add/insert a google calendar event using PHP, i am using the google API libraries via a [composer install](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient).

I have traced the error to the object being inserted (i have the token).  I did a json_encode of the event to be inserted to test with [google's online checker](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)  (for which i use the 'primary' calendarId)

```
   {
    "creator": null,
    "organizer": null,
    "summary": "Meeting with Bart Simpson",
    "id": null,
    "attendees": null,
    "htmlLink": null,
    "recurrence": null,
    "start": {
        "date": null,
        "timeZone":"Australia/Hobart",
        "dateTime": "2014-02-03T15:00:00+11:00"
    },
    "etag": null,
    "location": "-42.859634, 147.30928399999993",
    "recurringEventId": null,
    "gadget": null,
    "status": null,
    "updated": null,
    "description": "Visit",
    "iCalUID": null,
    "extendedProperties": null,
    "endTimeUnspecified": null,
    "sequence": null,
    "visibility": null,
    "guestsCanModify": null,
    "end": {
        "date": null,
        "timeZone":"Australia/Hobart",
        "dateTime": "2014-02-03T16:00:00+11:00"
    },
    "attendeesOmitted": null,
    "kind": null,
    "locked": null,
    "created": null,
    "colorId": "0",
    "anyoneCanAddSelf": null,
    "reminders": null,
    "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": null,
    "originalStartTime": null,
    "guestsCanInviteOthers": null,
    "transparency": null,
    "privateCopy": null
}
```

from which i get the response:

```
    400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid value for: null is not a valid value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value for: null is not a valid value"
 }
}
```

It seems the property name is missing from the  message.  "invalid value for **???**:"

I have tried removing items in a stepwise manner but it does not appear to work until only the start and end are left.  As all of the null entries are created by the API, I would have thought they were correct.

It was working before, and I changed something, but i am not sure what.  Am I missing something in my sleep deprived state?

Comment: I never worked out what the problem was here. I started the code again from scratch and got it to work eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this problem and after some time spent with Postman, I figured that Google API doesn't accept fields with null values (for some reason ). So I removed all null fields and left only ones with specified values and it worked! Hope this helps someone :)

P.S. You can play around and validate your requests using "Try this out" modal on Google Calendar Docs